# Is this a valid SQL query

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm

```
SELECT A.field1 FROM tbl1 AS A,tbl2 AS B WHERE A.field2=B.field2;
```

Or this the correct way

```
SELECT field1 FROM tbl1 AS A,tbl2 AS B WHERE A.field2=B.field2;
```

Assuming this is valid, how would you convert it into golang using gorm?

Answer (score 4):

Actually it depends. If field1 only exists in tbl1 or tbl2 then both would work. Otherwise first one is correct and removes ambiguity.

BTW, instead of using such old style inner join you should write that as:

```
SELECT A.field1 
FROM tbl1 AS A
inner join tbl2 AS B ON A.field2=B.field2;
```

With gorm:

```
db.Joins("Tbl2").Find(&tbl1)
```

EDIT? Since you are saying you don't know anything other than this SQL, you could use raw SQL as such:

```
var field1 string

rows, err := db.Raw("SELECT A.field1 FROM tbl1 AS A inner join tbl2 AS B on A.field2=B.field2 where b.Field3 = ?", "something").Rows()
defer rows.Close()
for rows.Next() {
  rows.Scan(&field1)

  // ...
}
```

Comment: Where are you including the conditions for A.field2 = B.field2 in the gorm query? Will it be a ```.Where()``` added to it? How would you write the original query in gorm? What if I have another condition in the where part as well?

Comment: What if I have another condition in the where part as well?
```SELECT A.field1 FROM tbl1 AS A, tb2 AS B WHERE A.field2=B.field2 AND B.field3 = {$var}``` 
This was the original query and I need to convert this query and a bunch others to gorm. Thank you so much for your help!!

Comment: It still would be a JOIN `on A.field2 = B.Field2` then you add your where criteria `Where b.field3 = yourValue`. In gorm `db.Joins("tbl2", db.Where(&tbl2{field3: searchvalue})).Find(&tbl1)`. Check gorm documentation: https://gorm.io/docs/query.html#Joins

Comment: BTW, I wouldn't really try writing database programs without first learning databases and particularly SQL. Life wouldn't be so easy using only ORMs. You can start learning SQL on w3schools.com.

Comment: The issue is I dont have the structure for the tables. I only know their names. How do I work with that

Comment: @UdayBhargav, then I don't know how you could work with gorm except raw SQL. Gorm basically requires structs and for that you need to know structures. Isn't that odd you are trying to use data without knowing what to expect. Adding a Raw SQL sample.

Answer (score 0):

```golang
type Tbl1 struct {
....
}

var Fields []struct {
   Field1 string
}

-- gorm

err := gorm.Model(&Tbl1{}).
   Joins("tbl2 ON tbl1.field2 = tbl2.field2").
   Select("tbl1.field1").
   Scan(&Fields).Error
if err!=nil {
 ...
}
```

Reference: https://gorm.io/docs/query.html

Answer (score 0):

**Models**

```golang
type tbl1 struct {
    field1 string
    field2 string
}

type tbl2 struct {
    field1 string
    field2 string
}
```

**SQL**

```sql
SELECT A.field1 FROM tbl1 A INNER JOIN tbl2 B ON A.field2 = B.field2
```

**Gorm**

```golang
db.
    Model(tbl1{}).
    Select("A.field1").
    Joins("INNER JOIN tbl2 B ON A.field2 = B.field2").
    Scan(&tbl1{})
```

Comment: What if I dont know the structure of the table?

Comment: As long as you are familiar with the structure of your structs, you should have no trouble using them as models and their fields for querying.